# Generate list of strings

Tags: python-3.6

Here's what is inside my CSV file

```
     Symbol
0     AACAF
1     AACAY
2     AACTF
3      AAGC
4     AAGIY
5     AAIGF
6     AAMAF
7      AAPH
8      AAPT
9      AAST
10    AATDF
11    AATGF
12    AATRL
13    AAUKF
14     AAWC
15     ABBY
16    ABCAF
17    ABCCF
18     ABCE
19    ABCFF
20    ABCZF
21    ABCZY
22    ABEPF
23     ABHD
24     ABHI
25     ABLT
26    ABLYF
27    ABNAF
28     ABNK
29    ABNRY
```

I would like to build a function which could create strings by batch of three symbols, e.g.

```
'AACAF,AACAY,AACTF'
'AAGC,AAGIY,AAIGF'
'AAMAF,AAPH,AAPT'
'AAST,AATDF,AATGF'
'AATRL,AAUKF,AAWC'
'AABY,ABCAF,ABCCF'
'ABCE,ABCFF,ABCZF'
'ABCZY,ABEPF,ABHD'
'ABHI,ABLT,ABLYF'
'ABNAF,ABNK,ABNRY'
```

I started what I want in using python, but I don't know how to complete it. I think I could use the csv module to do that.

```
with open(path, 'r') as csvfile:
    rows=[row for row in csvfile]

    batch_size = 100
    listing = []
    string = ''
    count = 0

    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        if count >= batch_size:
            listing.append(string)
            string = ''
            count = 0

        ','.join((string,row))
        count += 1
```

How could I do that with python 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = pandas.read_csv(path).Symbol.values
symbol_groups = numpy.split(arr, len(arr) // 3)
result = [','.join(symbols) for symbols in symbol_groups]
```

Should be doing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(path, 'r') as csvfile:
    rows=[row.strip('\n') for row in csvfile]

    batch_size = 100
    listing = []
    string = ''
    count = 0

    for index, row in enumerate(rows[1:]):
        if count >= batch_size or index == len(rows[1:])-1:
            listing.append(string)
            string = ''
            count = 0

        if count == 0:
            string = ''.join((string,row))
        else:
            string = ','.join((string,row))

        count += 1
```